# MySQL column specific user permissions

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table with a specific column that I don't want any normal users of the application to be able to edit, it should only be editable by an admin level user.

Although I've been developing with PHP for a while my knowledge of MySQL isn't as good (I'm correcting that). In the application UI I can just hide the controls to edit that column for non-admins but my understanding is that it's best to keep restrictions like this in the database as well? If so how would it be best to do this?

From my searching the only solution that I've found is to have a separate DB user connect to the database when a non-admin user logs in and use GRANT to restrict that users ability to change that column E.G.

```
GRANT INSERT (restricted_col) ON db.table TO 'restricted_user'@'host';
```

Is this the best method of doing it?

If this is the case is it common to keep database users under version control as well? And when putting changes onto a production server just a case of remembering to update the user permissions?

Comment: usually php applications happen to manage just fine using a single db user for all queries.

Comment: this sounds like overkill to me. I don't know of a single application (PHP or otherwise) that goes to this level of control over individual DB columns.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that I might have over thought this.

Comment: What you are doing is a good way to separate rights: Implement it at a level where you have oversight in a single (or just a few) lines of code or data. It prevents another developer (or yourself) in a later stage of accidentally writing code which allows a use to modify this data without really having to think this through why you limited the rights in the first place.

Comment: Good to know I wasn't off the mark then, I was thinking along those same lines. I was also thinking that if it was only restricted in PHP then if another method & different UI was written to INSERT into that table it would rely on the developer knowing & remembering to implement that check.